# "smart" JUnit test ordering

Tags: junit, ant

I want to add some hints to my build, to run certain tests "first" without re-running them later.

1. Simply add Class names to a "priority" string in an input parameter to my test task, or
2. Have JUnit's testers smart enough to remember/persist failing test class names, so that the next time around the builder runs those first.

What is the most idiomatic way of doing this in Ant?

Answer (score 2):

The following tools might help you to achieve the desired JUnit test execution order, but they depend on Eclipse usage:

1. [Continuous Testing for Eclipse (CT-Eclipse)](http://ct-eclipse.tigris.org/)
2. [JUnit Max](http://www.junitmax.com/)
3. [infinitest](http://infinitest.github.com/)

I have not used any of those tools, and I have no Ant-only solution.

You might consider these related posts:

- [Run JUnit automatically when building Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775465/run-junit-automatically-when-building-eclipse-project)
- [Starting unit tests automatically after saving a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330099/starting-unit-tests-automatically-after-saving-a-file)